# Starting with phone gap

Tags: javascript, html

i am very new to phone gap. i am building a vocabulary app as a project.

it is like on 1st page if i select an alphabet and on next page it should display words starting with that alphabet. i am facing problem in displaying words only starting with that particular alphabet which was being clicked on previous page. how can i do it???

```
function onDeviceReady()
      {
           if() 
           {
              document.getElementById("word").innerHTML="abase";
              document.getElementById("synonym").innerHTML="lower,degrade";
           }    


      }
```

this is the code of second page. what should i pass in if loop? 
and below its how i display it

```
<table name="tb1" border="2">

<tr> 
<td>word</td>
<td>synonym</td>

</tr>
<tr>    
<td id="word"></td>
<td id="synonym"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what type of issue you are facing? are you not able to get the word  entered on first page onto the next/second page.

Comment: i am not passing a word to another page. on button click i am able to open new page. but how do i display words on that button click only. that is the id of button of 1st page should pass on second page and it should compare if its A then words related to A should display.

Comment: are you using JQuery mobile or plain Javascript inside your cordova app?

Comment: its a phone gap app.. and using only javascript and html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HTML5 Local Storage feature** and it works well in phonegap apps.

(1) First save the user entered word or character in local storage

```
var word =  document.getElementById("word").value ;
localStorage.setItem("searchword", JSON.stringify(word) );
```

(2) on the second page, just get it back.

```
var a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchword"));
```

Using local storage, you can also add another feature in your app to show the history of last entered words. Just create an array in localstorage and use it to hold user inputs.

Later on to clear all data from local storage.

```
localStorage.clear();
```

**Edit:**
In order to identify which button (letter) was picked by the user, you have to create a function that will get the label or value of that button and then save it inside the local storage as mentioned above. Once this is done then change the page and retrieve the stored item and accordingly show the results.

*for example:*

```
//below js must run inside the first page
function saveSelectedChar() {
    var word =  document.getElementById("charA").value ; // charA is the button ID or value....its up to you either use ID or value to identify selected char
    localStorage.setItem("searchword", JSON.stringify(word) );

}
```

on second page:

```
function showWords() {

      var char = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchword"));

       // now search in your dictionary object and show the results
       searchInDictionary( char );
}
```

Comment: thank you... but if there are buttons of different alphabets and i want to display words on that alphabet on which i have clicked then how can i do it?

Comment: Okay, so your are having multiple html pages in your app and when user select a letter then it should show list of associated words on the next html page?

Comment: see this, it will help you :)

Comment: ok, so it works in a similar way as text box... thank you... :)

Comment: yes correct. see how to use value with buttons: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp   I hope this will help, just mark the answer